# VS code not suggesting declared functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My vscode does not detect suggestions. If you could look at the picture. I have defined a custom function onAddedPerson which my vscode instead of giving me a file shaped icon while suggesting gives me an abc. Even though it sounds like a minor problem but my vscode is generally horrible at suggestions.

[image: VSCODESNAP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want better intellisense in JavaScript, you need to use [JSDoc type tags](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), you can use [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/), or you can use typescript ([react with typescript guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-with-typescript-best-practices/)).

Main differences between flow and typescript are that flow is more functional programming oriented, while typescript is more object-oriented.

I'd definitely recommend using typescript with react as it's very workable to get well-typed react so intellisense works everywhere. And it seems that a lot of the community is going towards that route over flow.